# why is that there is a dark area around the buttons when they are tapped on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

the code is: https://codesandbox.io/s/gatsby-starter-default-og782

I used `styled-component` to style a `<a>` tag to be my button.

for example,

```
const CloseButton = styled.a`
  position: relative;
  font-size: 30px;
  top: 30vh;
`
```

And I implemented a hover effect with the `<a>` tag with `transform: translateY(-3px);`

```
  a {
    outline: none;
    font-size: ${fontSizes.medium};
    ${media.phablet` font-size: ${fontSizes.small};`}
    font-weight: 500;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-decoration-skip-ink: auto;
    color: inherit;
    position: relative;
    transition: ${theme.transition};
    cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 7px;
    &:hover,
    &:focus
     {
    transform: translateY(-3px);
    }
    -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none; 
  user-select: none;    

  }
```

Now it works fine on desktop. But when I view it on mobile devices(you can try the demo here https://og782.sse.codesandbox.io/)

There is a dark area around the buttons when they are tapped

Could someone please help me to get rid of this?

[image]

Comment: perhaps it's the `:active` pseudo-class?

Comment: @JaromandaX :active and what?

Comment: `and what?` huh? no, just the `:active` pseudo-class ... no and anything, all I said was the `:active` pseudo-class, didn't even imply there's an and after it - not sure what you're reading, but it's not anything I wrote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely this is because of `-webkit-tap-highlight-color`

You can try to make a transparent style:

```
a {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```